# How to create a dynamic datasource using SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, datasource, spring-data-jpa

I have a springboot application, with its own datasource (let's call DB1) set on properties working fine.

But this application needs do configure a **new** datasource (DB2), using some parameters the user have informed before and stored in DB1.

My idea is to create a named bean, so a specific part of my application can use to access DB2 tables. I think it is possible to do that by restarting the application, but I would like to avoid it though.

Besides, I need that some part of my code use the new datasource (spring data jpa, mappings, and so on). I don't know if this matter, but it is a web application, so I cannot create the datasource only for the request thread.

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a solution injecting the first `EntityManager` to get the connection parameters and using a `@PostConstruct` annotation to create the second datasource. The only problem with this approach is that I need to restart the application if the parameters are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has dynamic datasource routing if that's where you are headed.  In my case it is the same schema (WR/RO)

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

  @Autowired
  private DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

  @Override
  protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return DbContextHolder.getDbType();
  }

  public enum DbType {
    MASTER, WRITE, READONLY,  
  }
```

Then you need a custom annotation and an aspect

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ReadOnlyConnection {
}

@Aspect 
@Component
@Order(1)
public class ReadOnlyConnectionInterceptor {

  Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
  public void anyPublicMethod() {}

  @Around("@annotation(readOnlyConnection)")
  public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, ReadOnlyConnection readOnlyConnection) throws Throwable           {
    Object result = null;
    try {
      DbContextHolder.setDbType(DbType.READONLY);
      result = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
      DbContextHolder.clearDbType();
      return result;
    } finally {
      DbContextHolder.clearDbType();
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can act on you DB with the tag @ReadOnlyConnection

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@ReadOnlyConnection
public UnitDTO getUnitById(Long id) {
  return unitRepository.findOne(id);
}
```

An example can be found here: https://github.com/afedulov/routing-data-source.

I used that as a basis for my work although it is still in progress because I still need to resolve runtime dependencies  ( i.e. hibernate sharding ).

Comment: Please don't provide link-only answers, links may get broken and the answer becomes irrelevant. Put most important bits to your post directly.

Comment: Agreed. Added example behavior with full source link